# In-App-Purchase for version update

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have done changes in UI and one button for new version. It's an In-App-Purchase app. I read doc for how to add version. Is i need to change anything in In-App-Purchase for ManageInAppPurchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManageInAppPurchase is used to add products if exist in your application. If you have no products to be purchased from with in the application, the you don't need to do anything with this.

Comment: In version 1.0 i have one video for In-App-Purchase. In new version, i replace the old video with new video. Is i need to change in IAP?

Comment: For this you have to go to ManageInAppPurchase and add a product in it. If you add non consumable product don't forget to add restore button in app otherwise apple will reject the application.